# Introducing: Sudoku-Janpu

Tags: combinatorics, sudoku, retrograde-analysis

<sub>This is an entry into the [29<sup>th</sup> fortnightly topic challenge - Retrograde Analysis](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5858/fortnightly-topic-challenge-29-retrograde-analysis?cb=1).</sub>

### Scenario:

Alice and Bob were playing a game of Sudoku-Janpu.

**Alice:** I win.
**Bob:** *(looking at the board)* Oh man, not again!
**Alice:** You could have won before; I made a mistake.
**Bob:** Really?
**Alice:** *(pointing at the board several times)* See, if you went there instead of there I'd have had no legal move ... I should have gone there instead of there.
**Bob:** Aw... that makes it even worse! Want another game? This time I'm going to win.
**Alice:** *(chuckles)* We'll  see about that!

This was the final position:

[image: Sudoku-Janpu board]

For you to work out:

> **How did Alice win? How could Bob have won?**

Both answers **require proof**.

### Rules:

Sudoku-Janpu is a 2-player game played on a blank sudoku grid. *Janpu* means **jump** in Japanese.

> - The first player can play anywhere
> - After that, players have to play exactly a [knight's jump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_(chess)#Movement) away from the last play
> - A play consists of writing a number in a blank square, as long as the number is not in the same row, column or 3x3 box
> - The first person who cannot make a valid play loses

Comment: @boboquack thanks for clarifying; I'll delete my comment that provoked the clarification lest it now confuse readers :-).

Comment: I reread and think I understand it now, nevermind!

Comment: And if anyone wants to turn this game into a KotH on PPCG, go ahead! Someone's probably come up with this game before me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alice's last move must have been

> the 9 in the top left corner

because

> every other occupied square has a knight's-move neighbour empty square that can be filled legally. (Almost all have one that can be filled with a 1, in fact.)

Clearly Bob's previous move was

> the 4 lying southeast of that 9.

Now consider

> the square at the top left of the centre-left 3x3 box. Call it S. This has four neighbours, all of them squares Alice moves to at some point. After she moves to the *last* of these, Bob can move to S, at which point Alice has no vacant square to move to and Bob wins; and this is what Alice is referring to when she says Bob could have won.

We can't

> infer very much about which of those she actually moves to last, or when -- quite a number of different sequences of moves are consistent with the diagram in the question -- but after some discussion with @boboquack I have confirmed that the above is what he was wanting to see :-).

Comment: Perhaps I am. I haven't found a better way that actually proves anything yet, though :-).

Comment: And the fact that there are viable game-histories for each of Alice's next-to-last moves seems to me to show that there *can't* be a really simple proof. But, again, maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: (note to readers: earlier versions of my answer were much more complicated because I misunderstood how specific an answer OP was looking for.)